# operator && cannot be applied to bool and int c#

Tags: c#, operators

Operator && cannot be applied to bool and int C#?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter number1 : ");
        Console.Write("Enter number2 : ");
        Console.Write("Enter number3 : ");

        int getla1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int getla2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int getla3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (getla1 && getla2 > getla3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The third number is the smallest number");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well `getla1` is an int, not a `bool` (so not true or false). So what are you intending to check with `getla1`? That it's larger than 1? It's 0? 1 million?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The `&&` operator is the `logical and` operator.

Comment: What do you expect `if (getla1)` to do??? int can't be true or false?!

Comment: [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) was too hard to find? "The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its **bool operands**, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary."

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((getla1 > getla3) && (getla2 > getla3))
{
     // The third number is the smallest number
     Console.WriteLine("Het derde getal is de kleinste getal");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an integer like a boolean in C#.

If you are trying to check if `getla1` isn't 0 use `if (getla1 != 0 && getla2 > getla3) {}`.

Answer (score 2):

`getla1` is an integer. So there's no defined behavior for an integer treated as a boolean in C#. If you're used to dynamically typed languages where an integer is "truthy" if it is non-zero, then you'll need to check the integer against zero:

```
if (getla1 != 0 && getla2 > getla3) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

getla1 is an int.  && takes two bools.  Do you mean:

```
if (getla1 != 0 && getla2 > getla3)
```

or

```
if (getla1 > getla3 && getla2 > getla3)
```

?

Comment: See my answer, "Het derde getal is de kleinste getal" means "The third number is the smallest number"

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is check if the addition of `getla1` and `getla2` is greater than `getla3`

```
    if ((getla1 + getla2) > getla3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Het derde getal is de kleinste getal");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compare both values to see if they are greater than, if so, then do this:

```
if ((getla1 > getla3) && (getla2 > getla3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to understand the compiler error? The code `if (getla1 && getla2 > getla3)` means `if ((getal1) && (getal2 > getal3))`.

Since `getal1` is an `int`, you cannot use it as a condition, as conditions need to evaluate to a boolean.

You cannot compare multiple numbers to one that way. You're looking for this:

```
if ((getal1 > getal3) && (getal2 > getal3))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to check the conditions like this

```
(getla1 + getla2) > getla3
```